# JWPlayer Events are not working

Tags: javascript, events, jwplayer

I am using the JWPlayer to play a video file and after the video is done I want to show a message.
It says here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference

that you have to pass the `

```
events: {
   onComplete: function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'That's all folks!';
   }
  }
```

` code into the setup.

However the events are not working at all.. I tried it in different ways but it does not work.

I have seen this question multiple times on stack overflow but none of them have a solution.

Comment: Did you try onTime(callback)?

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't seem to fire any events. I don't get any error messages either.

Comment: Fixed.

I haven´t found the anwser online.
The javascript files were located before the ending body tag (`</body>`).

After the files were moved to before the ending head (`</head>`) tag the events worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I haven´t found the anwser online. The javascript files were located before the ending body tag `</body>`. After the files were moved to before the ending head1 `</head>` tag the events worked.